# Extract content from web pages and save as dataframe in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I try to extract content from [this link](https://www.cspea.com.cn/list/c01/gr2020bj1005297-3) in **the blue circle** from image below:

[image]
Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.cspea.com.cn/list/c01/gr2020bj1005297-3'
res = requests.get(url, verify = False)
html_page = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find_all(text=True)

output = ''
blacklist = [
    '[document]',
 'a',
 'b',
 'body',
 'div',
 'em',
 'h1',
 'h2',
 'h3',
 'head',
 'html',
 'i',
 'meta',
 'p',
 'script',
 # 'span',
 # 'td',
 # 'th',
 # 'title'
    # there may be more elements you don't want, such as "style", etc.
]

for t in text:
    if t.parent.name not in blacklist:
        output += '{} '.format(t)

print(output)
```

How could extract data and save the content as dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example as a basis to scrape the page (as I don't know chinese, I get all cells to dataframe - you can remove rows from the dataframe you don't need afterwards):

```
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.cspea.com.cn/list/c01/gr2021bj1000186"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, verify=False).content, "html.parser")

index, data = [], []
for th in soup.select(".project-detail-left th"):
    h = th.get_text(strip=True)
    t = th.find_next("td").get_text(strip=True)
    index.append(h)
    data.append(t)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=["value"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                                             value
项目名称                                     海南省三亚市吉阳区溪泽南路18号兰海水都花园29幢
项目编号                                               GR2021BJ1000186
受让方名称                                                           **
交易方式                                                          网络竞价

...etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, could we reshape dataframe by setting the first columns as header of dataframe and and `value` column as first rows?

Comment: @ahbon You can transpose the dataframe - try `df  = df.T`