# Drop down to the bottom of the page and get urls for each entry in Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

With help from [the first link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66797532/extract-content-from-web-pages-and-save-as-dataframe-in-python), I'm able to crawler one single page's desired contents.

Next step I would like come back parent page and drop down to the bottom of the page, then loop all the transactions entries from [the second link](https://www.cspea.com.cn/list?c=C01&i=1&p=5000-999999999&s=A06,A07), pass the urls to the code from **the first link**.

My final object is to crawl data and append the contents as dataframe.

How could I do that? Thanks.

[image]

Code:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'DNT': '1',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Origin': 'https://www.cspea.com.cn',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://www.cspea.com.cn/list?c=C01&i=1&p=5000-999999999&s=A06,A07',
    'Accept-Language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9',
}

data = {
  'filter_projectText': '',
  'filter_projectClassifyCode': 'C01',
  'filter_tagCode': '',
  'filter_industryCode': '',
  'filter_industryCodeTwo': '',
  'filter_projectType': '1',
  'filter_tradInstitutionId': '',
  'filter_zone': '',
  'filter_groupZone': '',
  'filter_minPrice': '',
  'filter_maxPrice': '',
  'filter_minTradeValue': '5000',
  'filter_maxTradeValue': '999999999',
  'filter_minPercent': '',
  'filter_maxPercent': '',
  'filter_startDate': '',
  'filter_endDate': '',
  'filter_startTradeDate': '',
  'filter_endTradeDate': '',
  'filter_startPreDate': '',
  'filter_endPreDate': '',
  'filter_businessStatus': 'A06,A07',
  'filter_isGz': '',
  'filter_isHot': '',
  'filter_publishDateSort': 'desc',
  'filter_projectPriceSort': '',
  'filter_tradeValueSort': '',
  'filter_startExpireDate': '',
  'filter_endExpireDate': '',
  'pageIndex': '8',
  'pageSize': '12',
  'sysCode': '1',
  'filter_textDateSort': ''
}

response = requests.post('https://www.cspea.com.cn/proxy/projectInterface/project/searchIndex', headers=headers, data=data, verify = False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `totalPage` value in the response, so you can use this to loop over the pages and grab the data and dump it all to a `df`.

Here's how:

```
import json

import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'DNT': '1',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_1_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Origin': 'https://www.cspea.com.cn',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'https://www.cspea.com.cn/list?c=C01&i=1&p=5000-999999999&s=A06,A07',
    'Accept-Language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9',
}

data = {
    'filter_projectText': '',
    'filter_projectClassifyCode': 'C01',
    'filter_tagCode': '',
    'filter_industryCode': '',
    'filter_industryCodeTwo': '',
    'filter_projectType': '1',
    'filter_tradInstitutionId': '',
    'filter_zone': '',
    'filter_groupZone': '',
    'filter_minPrice': '',
    'filter_maxPrice': '',
    'filter_minTradeValue': '5000',
    'filter_maxTradeValue': '999999999',
    'filter_minPercent': '',
    'filter_maxPercent': '',
    'filter_startDate': '',
    'filter_endDate': '',
    'filter_startTradeDate': '',
    'filter_endTradeDate': '',
    'filter_startPreDate': '',
    'filter_endPreDate': '',
    'filter_businessStatus': 'A06,A07',
    'filter_isGz': '',
    'filter_isHot': '',
    'filter_publishDateSort': 'desc',
    'filter_projectPriceSort': '',
    'filter_tradeValueSort': '',
    'filter_startExpireDate': '',
    'filter_endExpireDate': '',
    'pageIndex': '1',
    'pageSize': '12',
    'sysCode': '1',
    'filter_textDateSort': ''
}

end_point = 'https://www.cspea.com.cn/proxy/projectInterface/project/searchIndex'
df_container = []
with requests.Session() as connection:
    response = connection.post(end_point, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
    last_page = int(response.json()["result"]["totalPage"]) + 1
    for page in range(1, last_page):
        data["pageIndex"] = str(page)
        print(f"Going through page {page}...")
        r = connection.post(end_point, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False).json()
        df_container.extend(json.loads(r["result"]["data"]))

df = pd.DataFrame(df_container)

cols = ['publishDate', 'expireDate', 'tradeDate']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, unit='ms').dt.date)

df.to_csv("items_scraped.csv", index=False)
```

Output:

A `.csv` file with 254 entries. You can drop any columns you want and reshape the `df` to your liking.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, did the infos scrapied from details page or list page? I don't find any `transaction date` column from csv file. For example, one of item's date's xpath is `//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/main/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]`.

Comment: It all comes from the end-point. I don't read Chinese so I don't know which page tag should be mapped to the column you mention. It might be the case, that some of the info is in the `HTML` itself, but I haven't checked that.

Comment: These are, I believe, the `publishDate` and `expireDate` but those are in milliseconds, so you'd have to parse the values to get a human readable dates.

Comment: Sorry, I found it, in csv file, the name is `tradeDate`, but it's value such as `1.6166E+12`, etc.

Comment: So it seems your new code did't containing the code in the last post. Is it possible to obtain the item's url and pass them to the code here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66797532/extract-content-from-web-pages-and-save-as-dataframe-in-python.

Comment: Hold on, too many questions at once. The dates are in milliseconds and you need to parse them to get a human readable format. The urls are (sort of) in the `df`. Use `projectCode` to build urls and append to `df`. If you have a particular issue, open a new question, as comments are not meant for debugging.

Comment: I create `df['url'] = 'https://www.cspea.com.cn/list/c01/' + df['projectCode']`, then I need pass the `url` column to the first code and append result to dataframe.

Comment: Open a new question. I'll have a look later on.

Comment: I posted a new question, thanks for your kind help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66890578/pass-url-columns-values-one-by-one-to-web-crawler-code-in-python