# Pass url column's values one by one to web crawler code in Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

Based on the answered code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66880710/drop-down-to-the-bottom-of-the-page-and-get-urls-for-each-entry-in-python/66883736?noredirect=1#comment118231557_66883736), I'm able to create a new column: `df['url'] = 'https://www.cspea.com.cn/list/c01/' + df['projectCode']`.

Next step I would like to pass the `url` column's values to the following code and append all the scrapied contents as dataframe.

```
import urllib3
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.cspea.com.cn/list/c01/gr2021bj1000186" # url column's values should be passed here one by one
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, verify=False).content, "html.parser")
index, data = [], []
for th in soup.select(".project-detail-left th"):
    h = th.get_text(strip=True)
    t = th.find_next("td").get_text(strip=True)
    index.append(h)
    data.append(t)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=["value"])
print(df)
```

How could I do that in Python? Thanks.

**Updated:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('items_scraped.xlsx')

data = []
urls =  df.url.tolist()
for url_link in urls:

    url = url_link
    # url = "https://www.cspea.com.cn/list/c01/gr2021bj1000186"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, verify=False).content, "html.parser")
    
    index, data = [], []
    for th in soup.select(".project-detail-left th"):
        h = th.get_text(strip=True)
        t = th.find_next("td").get_text(strip=True)
        index.append(h)
        data.append(t)
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=["value"])
    df = df.T
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    print(df)

df.to_excel('result.xlsx', index = False)
```

But it only saved one rows into excel file.

Comment: assuming the rest of your code is correct you need to append the df within the loop to a global list and then call pd.concat on that list outside the loop.  Currently, you are only working with the last iteration as you overwrite df each time. There are plenty of existing questions covering this,

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, could u pls edit my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the `dfs` generated in the loop. You could add them to a list and then call `pd.concat` on that list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('items_scraped.xlsx')

# data = []
urls =  df.url.tolist()
dfs = []

for url_link in urls:

    url = url_link
    # url = "https://www.cspea.com.cn/list/c01/gr2021bj1000186"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, verify=False).content, "html.parser")
    
    index, data = [], []
    for th in soup.select(".project-detail-left th"):
        h = th.get_text(strip=True)
        t = th.find_next("td").get_text(strip=True)
        index.append(h)
        data.append(t)
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=["value"])
    df = df.T
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    print(df)
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.to_excel('result.xlsx', index = False)
```

Comment: Do you think `data = []` out of loop is necessary? Because I found `index, data = [], []` inside the loop code.

Comment: I left that code as it was. I cannot run the whole thing because the link you posted (which I assume generated the xlsx data) doesn't work for me. data looks like it needs to be in the loop as it is used to generate the individual df.

Comment: Sorry for the inconveniance. I found it works perfectly as well even if i commented `data = []`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 urls =  df.url.tolist()
```

To create a list of URLs and then iterate through them using f string to insert each one into your base url

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question, it only saved one row. Please check.